# Socket.io : New connections are created with only one client connected

Tags: html, node.js, server, socket.io, client

I have a minimalist socket.io with running on **Node.js** with a **HTML client**.

This is my minimalist server code (server.js):

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`new connection : ${socket.id}`);
});
```

and my minimalist client code (client.html):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000/'); 
  </script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open client.html I get the message:

```
new connection : DedBsiEyAHLIu86oAAB0
```

which is fine, however after 7-8 seconds I get other new connection messages with differents socket ID :

```
new connection : K3DUMN7SJ0tOU7TsAACO
new connection : 3kCOVCz9fwRWtIypAACP
new connection : HgMVgpeP7raq1c4YAACQ
new connection : U6-lD-3lT1vT39_oAACR
new connection : aQCKYpBUVXD7t8WIAACS
```

On Chrome devtools-network tab, the same repeating message is displayed (which populate the new connection) :

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NYCWok4
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Regards

Pierre.

Comment: What happens if you specify the transport layer? (Looks like you using long polling) It may be falling back to long polling and trying to reconnect 

io.connect(server, {

          "transports": ['websocket']
})

Comment: I realized that I was using a CORS enable plug-in with Chrome, I disable it which solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was using a CORS enable plug-in with Chrome, I disable it which solve my problem